# Removing images using event handlers

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I really can't figure out how to solve this problem. Here is the question and the original code.

> Question: Implement the setup function that registers a click event
>   handler and implements the following logic: When the button of class
>   remove is clicked, its parent  element should be removed from the
>   gallery.

```
function setup() {
  **//IM SUPPOSED TO PUT MY CODE ONLY IN THIS PART//**
}

// Example case. 
document.body.innerHTML = `
<div class="image">
  <img src="firstimage.jpg" alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="secondimage.jpg" alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>`;

setup();

document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].click();
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

This is what I have. As soon as I run the program, it removes the first image without the user clicking on it. And I have no idea how to fix it.

```
function setup() {
    var myImage = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
    document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].
    addEventListener("click", function(){
    myImage[0].parentNode.removeChild(myImage[0]);}); 
}

// Example case. 
document.body.innerHTML = `
<div class="image">
  <img src="firstimage.jpg" alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="secondimage.jpg" alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>`;

setup();

document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].click();
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

You want to *iterate* over each element, which is a lot more elegant than assigning to each element in the collection individually, so try something like this instead:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.remove')
  .forEach(button => 
    button.addEventListener('click', () => button.parentElement.remove())
  )
```

`.remove` removes an element from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the first image is removed automatically before you even click on it is because of the `document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].click();` which is directly under the `setup()` function call.
Which means as soon as the function is called to perform the task, `document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].click();` is immediately performed and removes the first image using index 0 and `click()`.
So to solve this, try removing that [0] index or remove `document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].click();` which is not useful in your case, and see how it goes.

```js
function setup() {
    let myImage = document.querySelectorAll(".remove").forEach(function (button){
        button.addEventListener('click', function(){
            button.parentElement.remove()
        })
    });
}
    
// Example case. 
document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div class="image">
      <img src="firstimage.jpg" alt="First">
      <button class="remove">X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="secondimage.jpg" alt="Second">
      <button class="remove">X</button>
    </div>`;
    
setup();
    
document.getElementsByClassName("remove").click();
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';

const ImageGallery = ({links}) =>{
const [data,setData] = useState(links)
const removeElement = (removeElement) => {
    const newsetdata = data.filter((index) => index !== removeElement);
    setData(newsetdata);
    console.log(newsetdata)
    // setData(data.splice(index,1));
};

  return (
    <>
      <div>      
        {
          data.map((abc,i,data)=> {           
          return(
              <div key={i}> 
                  <img src={abc} alt="images"/> 
                  <button onClick={() => removeElement(data[i])}>X
                  </button>
              </div>
            
            )             

          })
        }
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default ImageGallery;
```

Comment: Code-only answer